# appeal to a multidimensional array react

Tags: json, reactjs, babeljs

Tell me, please, how can I refer, by the example of this code, to the final array?

```
{  
   "main":[  
      {  
         "dates":[  
            {  
               "9":[  
                  {  
                     "[\"no\"]":{  
                        "2018-09-02":1,
                        "2018-09-21":300,
                        "2018-09-03":2
                     },
                     "[\"yes\"]":{  
                        "2018-09-21":300
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "10":[  
                  {  
                     "[\"no\"]":{  
                        "2018-10-10":14,
                        "2018-10-11":3,
                        "2018-10-17":5,
                        "2018-10-23":3,
                        "2018-10-18":1
                     },
                     "[\"yes\"]":{  

                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I already got an array dates, i can select the desired array from dates like `dates[0]`, but now I want to refer to the lowest element
I tried the following `dates[0][0], dates[0].normal`but none of them helped
me :(

Please help me get the value of the first element in `[\"no\"]`

Answer (score -1):

> main[0*][9**][0*]["[\"normal\"]"**]

*- array order

**- value in array